# I am trying to extract a substring from a given string using Regex on Google Sheets for the first time. Which Regex pattern should I use to do so?

Tags: regex, string, google-sheets, substring, delimiter

I have started learning Regex recently and I was given a string as follows:

```
T10BestFruits_Mango_7-Slices_Thick_Daily_noshare_BD5567#Aware#SeasonalFruits#NA#NA|FreshMangoes-6x5-NPM-5300000-Nov22
```

I want to extract `6x5` using `REGEXEXTRACT` function but I cannot find the right Regex pattern that will do it perfectly. Is there any regex pattern that will give me "6x5" directly without any delimiters or words attached?

I first tried using `([|.*?]\w*[-.*?]\w*[-.*?]\w*[-.*?]\w*[-.*?]\w*)` to extract the substring but the result came out as `|FreshMangoes-6x5-NPM-5300000-Nov22`.

Then I tried `[|](.*)[-]` which gave me `FreshMangoes-6x5-NPM-5300000` and `-[\w*]+-` which gave me `-6x5-`.

What I needed was `6x5` exactly. There should be no delimiters in this substring.

Comment: You'r close, but try `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"-(\d+x\d+)-")` possibly?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sql
=REGEXEXTRACT(col, ".*\|.*?-(\w+)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T65Se3/1). *Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\|` - a `|` char
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `-` - a hyphen
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more alphanumeric/underscore chars.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1; "-(\d+x\d+)-")
```